# How to fill the chessboard with domino?

Tags: algorithm

How we can to fill the chessboard with domino and we have a some blocks. and chessboard is `n x m`. and the places filled with ordered numbers.

Test :

[image]

Answer like this :

[image]

input give n , m and k. `k` is number of blocks.
and next k lines give blocks such as `6 7` or `4 9`.

sorry for my English.

Comment: I try but not found any solution. not homework/interview question.

Comment: I don't understand what `6 7` and `4 9` stand for, can you please clarify that?

Comment: It seems to me that this question can only get either a highly theoretical or else a very long answer, which greatly decreases the likelihood of it getting a good answer at all. If you provide more information (e.g. decide on a representation for the board, blocks and placing of dominoes), including code, it will help.

Comment: @IVlad: They stand for "block between squares 6 and 7" and the same for squares 4 and 9.

Comment: @Jon - I see, thanks. @OP - have you tried a brute force backtracking algorithm? I would say one solution should be found pretty fast even with such an approach. How big is your board? Using what @AakashM suggested will speed this up.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea. In your example board, it is immediately obvious that squares `7` `9` and `14` must contain domino 'ends', that is to say it must be the case that there are dominos covering `2-7`, `8-9`, and `14-15`.

(In case it's not 'immediately obvious', the rule I used is that a square with 'walls' on three sides dictates the orientation of the domino covering that square)

If we place those three dominos, it may then be the case that there are more squares to which the same rule now applies (eg `20`).

By iterating this process, we can certainly make progress towards our goal, or alternatively get to a place where we know it can't be achieved.

See how far that gets you.

*edit* also, note that in your example, the lower-left corner 2x2 (squares 11 12 16 17) is not uniquely determined - a 90 degree rotation of the depicted arrangement would also work - so you will have to consider such situations. If you are looking for *any* solution, you must come up with a way of arbitrarily picking one of many possibilities; if you are trying to enumerate *all* possibilities, you will have to come up with a way of finding them all!